# PHP Form broken

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having problems getting a PHP email form to work. It's copied and pasted from another website I designed (which works fine) - the only thing i've done differently is changed the file structure a bit to tidy up.

Previously, all the main html pages were located in the root directory, and component files (JS, PHP, images, fonts etc) were located in a html directory - so for example `$root/contact us.html`, and components in `$root/html/js/forms.js`.

This time i've just removed the html directory, so all the files and folder sit in the root directory - example - $root/contact us.html, `$root/js/forms.js`.

I've updated the PHP and JS files so they all point in the right direction, but the form now isn't working.

Can anyone spot what I've done wrong?

Here is the code...

**HTML**

```
<form id="project-contact-form" action="javascript:void(0)" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div id="success-project-contact-form" class="vb-blue">Awesome - your message was sent! We'll be in touch soon.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name *" class="big-input">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" class="big-input">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail *" class="big-input">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="select-style big-select">
        <select name="subject" id="subject" class="big-input">
          <option value="">What's your message about?</option>
          <option value="general">- a general enquiry</option>
          <option value="product">- product related</option>
          <option value="delivery">- about a delivery</option>
          <option value="complaint">- a complaint</option>
          <option value="b2b">- a business proposal</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Your message" rows="6" class="big-textarea"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <button id="project-contact-us-button  margin-bottom-35" type="submit" class="btn btn-medium btn-rounded white bg-vb-red sbold-txt">SEND MESSAGE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
"use strict";
    /*==============================================================
    form to email
    ==============================================================*/
    $("#success-project-contact-form").hide();
    //Project Contact us form
    $('#project-contact-us-button').on("click", function () {
        var error = ValidationProjectContactForm();
        if (error) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/project-contact-form.php",
                data: $("#project-contact-form").serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    // Un-comment below code to redirect user to thank you page.
                    //window.location.href="thank-you.html";

                    $('input[type=text],textarea').each(function () {
                        $(this).val('');
                    })
                    $("#success-project-contact-form").html(result);
                    $("#success-project-contact-form").fadeIn("slow");
                    $('#success-project-contact-form').delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    function ValidationProjectContactForm() {
        var error = true;
        $('#project-contact-form input[type=text]').each(function (index) {
            if (index == 0) {
                if ($(this).val() == null || $(this).val() == "") {
                    $("#project-contact-form").find("input:eq(" + index + ")").addClass("required-error");
                    error = false;
                } else {
                    $("#project-contact-form").find("input:eq(" + index + ")").removeClass("required-error");
                }
            } else if (index == 2) {
                if (!(/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test($(this).val()))) {
                    $("#project-contact-form").find("input:eq(" + index + ")").addClass("required-error");
                    error = false;
                } else {
                    $("#project-contact-form").find("input:eq(" + index + ")").removeClass("required-error");
                }
            }

        });
        return error;
    }

    /*==============================================================
    End form to email
    ==============================================================*/
```

**and the PHP**

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $name =$_POST["name"];  
    $from =$_POST["email"]; 
    $phone=$_POST["phone"]; 
    $comment=$_POST["comment"]; 
    $subject=$_POST["subject"];

// Email Receiver Address
    $receiver="info@1230.co";
    $subject="Website Contact Form";
    $message = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Website Contact Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width='50%' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr>
    <td colspan='2' align='center' valign='top'><img style=' margin-top: 15px; ' src='img/logo-forms.png' ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width='50%' align='right'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align='left'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 5px 7px 0;'>Name:</td>
    <td align='left' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 0 7px 5px;'>".$name."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 5px 7px 0;'>Email:</td>
    <td align='left' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 0 7px 5px;'>".$from."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 5px 7px 0;'>Phone:</td>
    <td align='left' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 0 7px 5px;'>".$phone."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 5px 7px 0;'>Subject:</td>
    <td align='left' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 0 7px 5px;'>".$subject."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; border-bottom:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 5px 7px 0;'>Message:</td>
    <td align='left' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; border-bottom:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 0 7px 5px;'>".nl2br($comment)."</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <'.$from.'>' . "\r\n";
   if(mail($receiver,$subject,$message,$headers))  
   {

//Success Message
      echo "The message has been sent!";
   }
    else
   {

//Fail Message
      echo "The message could not been sent!";
   }
}
?>
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You have `url: "php/project-contact-form.php",`. If everything is located in the root directory, you shouldn't have `php/` prefix.

Comment: Are you seeing any 404 errors in the console?

Comment: The PHP script shouldn't care where it's located. As long as you give the correct URL in the `$.ajax` call it should work.

Comment: Your variable name `error` is confusing. It's true when there's no error.

Comment: sorry -to clarify, all php files, js files etc are in respective folders in the root directory. for example all php files are in $root/php/phpfile.php.

Comment: Developer Tools should show the full URL that you're trying to call. It shouldn't be hard for you to check that the files are in the correct location.

Comment: no errors in the console

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for us to tell you what's wrong. You should be able to find everything you need in the browser's console and your webserver logs.

Comment: "form isn't working" isn't enough of a problem description. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: And do you think you could post the PHP without double-spacing it, and fix the indentation? It's a lot more scrolling because of that.

Comment: i'll fix the double-spacing. So when I fill the form and click Send Message - nothing happens. I'm not seeing any feedback in the console regarding an error.

Comment: Have you tried using the Network tab of DevTools to see what parameters you're sending and what the response is?

Comment: If the script worked in a different location, then there's nothing wrong with the script itself. The only possible problem can be with URLs, and you should be able to see that in DevTools.

Comment: noyhing in the network tab. I thought that also, that the script itself is fine and it may just be a problem with the URLs. But i've tried changing them with no success.

Comment: If there's nothing in the network tab, that means it isn't sending the ajax request at all. Try single-stepping through the event handler.

Comment: "Try single-stepping through the event handler." - what does that mean?

Comment: Looking through the Network tab, I can see the html and js are being called, but not the php file.

Comment: nothing in the event handler related to the submit button click event

Comment: Set a breakpoint using the JavaScript debugger. When it stops at the breakpoint, click on the "Step over the next function call" button in the debugger. http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820

Comment: Is the event handler in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: First of all make sure that your server allows mail() function from PHP. Then I suggest you to handle the "submit" event of the form with jquery.

Do you use a .htaccess rules for url rewriting? Are you sure that the url "php/project-contact-form.php" in Ajax request is correct? If the html file is in the main root, maybe the url can be "./php/project-contact-form.php" or "/php/project-contact-form.php". Try to log in console the different url response of "success: function(data) {}" and handle the "error: function(a, b, c) {}" in Ajax function, that show to you if and what errors happen.

Comment: I'm sorry guys - thats all a bit too advanced for me - I'm really just a designer, not a developer. My knowledge of code is limited.

Comment: I can supply a test url if it would help a diagnosis?

Comment: if not - can someone recommend an idiot-proof email form I can copy and paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested out your code and the error is in your html code you have `id="project-contact-us-button  margin-bottom-35"` as shown in below code.

```
<button id="project-contact-us-button  margin-bottom-35" type="submit" class="btn btn-medium btn-rounded white bg-vb-red sbold-txt">SEND MESSAGE</button>
```

You then assign a click event handler to `project-contact-us-button`

```
//Project Contact us form
    $('#project-contact-us-button').on("click", function () {
```

To make your code work remove `margin-bottom-35`. Ids must not contain whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc.) as specified here [www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp), I don't know if that was a typo but that's whats breaking the code

```
<button id="project-contact-us-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-medium btn-rounded white bg-vb-red sbold-txt">SEND MESSAGE</button>
```

also if refering to a top level directory use `../`

```
 url: "../php/project-contact-form.php",
```